# Checkboxes created in a loop in Angular component show incorrect selected state

Tags: angular

I'm creating several checkboxes based on values of array in a *ngFor loop. 
When I click on the one of those checkboxes it is marked as selected, but also another one is shown as selected but in the model I see that only the first's checkbox value has been changed.

An example on [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PZ9HZQ4ltwVVZ7Xh6R3K?p=preview)

My component is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <div *ngFor="let item of schedule; let i = index">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="schedule[i]">
        </div>
       <span>{{schedule | json}}</span>
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  schedule: boolean[] = [];

  constructor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            this.schedule.push(false);
        }
    }
}
```

What can be incorrect in the code to cause it?

Comment: This seems more like a bug on the angular version that you are using. Nothing to do with your code

Comment: Well, I just create a separated array to bind the values of `[(ngModel)]` and it seems to work fine [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0siQCuvSDOJDwfEZsk0D?p=info).

Comment: @developer033 wow, indeed, thanks. do you know why using a separate array helps?

Comment: @SvetlanaKopylova it's something related to the change detection... each time you click (check) a checkbox, the content of array (schedule) automatically changes...

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <div *ngFor="let item of schedule; let i = index">
            <input 
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="'checkbox_' + i"
                  name="'checkbox_' + i"
                  [(ngModel)]="schedule[i]">
            <label [attr.for]="'checkbox_' + i"></label>
        </div>
       <span>{{schedule | json}}</span>
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  schedule: boolean[] = [];

  constructor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            this.schedule.push(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the same issue when run this code http://plnkr.co/edit/nu3kLnxRg1E1kWMY0J6m

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the very same problem I think. After a while, I found that tracking helps.

In template...

```
<span *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

In component...

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

I guess it helps angular change detection mechanism, and prevents instantiating the ngFor DOM instances too many times. Maybe a guru can give us a more precise explanation...